# Making a div fill 100% height of screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

Heres an image of my website right now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/McdLD.jpg

The section says "What is Spheroid" is ment to be my content container. However, I can't seem to make it go from the header to the footer.

My HTML code:

```
<div id="container">
    <h2>What is Spheroid?</h2>
</div>
```

My CSS Code:

```
html, body {
    background-image:url(001.png);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    width: 800px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #38788E;
}
```

I've tried using the "height: 100vh;" property, but it makes the container go beyond the footer so the page needs to be scrolled.

Also think it might have to be done with JavaScript, but that's a field where I'm going to need some support.

Thank you guys in advance :)

- EDIT -

So I figured from one of the answers, that my div was inside another div. So I fixed this, and with the same code as provided it not looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANqUZ.png
Thought it might have been the bg size, but as it is only set to "cover" it shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: `height` doesn't do anything without a `position`

Comment: @adeneo Allright, so I tried adding a position. It makes my container go all to the left instead of the middle + it goes below the footer again just like the 100vh

Comment: Viewport !== screen. What are you actually trying to achieve? A full-screen window?

Comment: duplicate of a duplicate of a duplica...whatever

Comment: The box that contains the spheroid text. I want it to be a width of 800px and fill from header to footer

Comment: Exactly, you phrased it better :P

Comment: add `* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}` and see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got your requirement, **flex box layout** is your friend.

View the demo in **full page** mode:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #eee;
}
header {
  height: 40px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
#container {
  flex: 1;
  width: 800px;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
footer {
  height: 30px;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<div id="container"></div>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Another approach with `box-sizing`:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  background: #eee;
}
header {
  height: 40px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
#container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
footer {
  height: 30px;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<div id="container"></div>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: Didn't change a thing :/

Comment: What happens if you add a width

Comment: I did, was just thinking if it did diffrence positionwise

Comment: @JonDier Provided two solutions. Personally I'd go with `flex` layout for it could handle even more complicated layouts. However `box-sizing` is enough for this particular case as well.

Comment: Worked with the flex! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you placed your `<div id="container">` inside another div or any parent element (except `html` and `body`). If so, the parent element/s don't have a height of 100%. If you add `height:100%;` to the parent element your container must fill the entire height of the parent element.

I tested your code provided and it's working.

Comment: That seems to be the issue, edited my post with the current state of the problem